# Unique results from database?

Tags: sql

I am selecting all badge numbers from a database where category is equal to 1.

```
category | badge number
0        | 1
1        | 1
2        | 5
1        | 1
```

Sometimes the category is duplicated, is there a way to only get unique badge numbers from the database?

So above there is two 1's in category, each with badge number 1. How can I make sure the result only gives '1' rather than '1,1'

Comment: When I google for "unique results from database" the solution is on the first result page. Maybe you should use google the next time before you ask a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DISTINCT key word in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT badge_number FROM Your_Table WHERE category = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the distinct keyword in your select.

```
select distinct badge_number from table_name where category = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Select Distinct` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT [badge number] from table 
where Category=1
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select Distinct Badgenumber from table where Category = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT BadgeNumber FROM dbo.TableName
Where Category = 1
```

Edited:
Ohh, there are so many posts already .... !!